# How to add Ripple effect for list item in expandable listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I am creating an application which consist of expandable listview i want to make a ripple effect for the list item in the expandable listview for which i have created a ripple drawable and added color in it and changed the android:background in the expandable listview to android:listselector but still the ripple effect is not working in the application.

Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/colorlightAccent">
<item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</ripple>
```

Xml:

```
    <codingtown.coconut.libraries.expandablelistview.ExpandableHeightListView
                android:id="@+id/detaillist_daybook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_drawable"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:scrollingCache="false"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true">

            </codingtown.coconut.libraries.expandablelistview.ExpandableHeightListView>
```

Comment: set the ripple background to item  view of list.

Comment: @PushpendraChoudhary How it has to be done can be explain it detailed

Comment: To set the ripple background to the itemview of the list, just add the attribute: android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"` listview item layout

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `android:id="@android:id/mask"` inside ur ripple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/colorlightAccent">
<item  android:id="@android:id/mask"android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</ripple>
```

First try a visible color for your ripple. If you background color is also white, you wont be able to see.

Also dont forget to add a backward compatible drawable if your app is supported on android versions less that 5.0.